# debugging ByteArrayOutputStream string comparison

Tags: java, encoding

I have a strange problem with Java's ByteArrayOutputStream..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
    String expected = "{x={x=4, y=true}, y=true}";
    printToStream(ps);

    try {
        String content =  new String(baos.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(">content : "+content);
        System.out.println("-expected: "+expected);
        printBytes(content);
        printBytes(expected);
        if(content.equals(expected)==false) //HERE
            throw new RuntimeException( "program failed");
        baos.close();

    } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(" failed string extraction");
    } catch ( IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(" cannote close the stream");
    } 
}
```

The program ends with "program failed" exception because the strings are not equals, however on Eclipse console they look identical:

```
>content : {x={x=4, y=true}, y=true}
-expected: {x={x=4, y=true}, y=true}
```

Furthermore, to inspect single bytes of strings (because if I can isolate singol characters I can find what's wrong with string creation or encoding) I created a method to look at hex values of their bytes., but they are not printed!

```
public static void printBytes( String st){
    String bytes="";
    for(byte it: st.getBytes())
        st+=Integer.toHexString(it)+" ";
    System.out.println("HexValues: "+bytes);
}
```

Instead of HexValues I got an empty string

```
HexValues: 
HexValues:
```

further investigation in documentation of `getBytes()` method bring to this

> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default charset is unspecified

However, if I provide a charset that should accept all possible characters (UTF8 or UTF16) as parameter of `getBytes`, it still fails (since String is UTF16 is should be always possible to convert it to UTF8 or UTF16 in theory, the only conversions that should fail are for example to ASCII for non ASCII characters).

The method `printToStream( PrintStream ps)` is part of specifications so I cannot change it.

**The real problem is:** I need to understand why the `equals` method of String return false.

EDIT:
After answer pointing to correct debug code I got:

```
HexValues:  fffffffe  ffffffff  0  74  0  72  0  75  0  65  0  d  0  a 
HexValues:  fffffffe  ffffffff  0  74  0  72  0  75  0  65  0  a
```

It was a missing carriage return `0x0d`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code at

```
 st+=Integer.toHexString(it)+" ";
 bytes+=Integer.toHexString(it)+" ";//use this instead
```

this error results in function input modification: content and expected are modified

Comment: Oh uao, It was going to be an hell searching an error in wrong place, the two strings are now :
`HexValues:  fffffffe  ffffffff  0  74  0  72  0  75  0  65  0  d  0  a ` and
`HexValues:  fffffffe  ffffffff  0  74  0  72  0  75  0  65  0  a `

Answer (score 1):

In the method you are not changing the string value that you prints. Therefore value of bytes is empty. You are changing the argument string.

you should use

```
public static void printBytes( String st){
    String bytes="";
    for(byte it: st.getBytes())
        bytes+=Integer.toHexString(it)+" "; // not st
    System.out.println("HexValues: "+bytes);
}
```

for the equality case. May be you are having spaces in the string. Try to trim the string and do the compparision

```
if(content.trim().equals(expected.trim()) // no need to explicitly check if true or flase
```